# Passport local mongoose not matching exact email

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport-local

I am using **mongodb** and **node js** at my side. I am using **passport local mongoose** to `register` and `login` the user.

Now the issue which i am facing is: At the time of registration. If user register with `rajat.test@gmail.com` and he tries to login with `rajat.Test@gmail.com`. Then the app is giving the access to the user, which is wrong. Because at the time of registration , user gave all letters in lowercase.

So i only want to confirm that, How can i enable case senstivity while authenticating in passport local mongoose?

Below is my registration and login code

**register**

```
const user = new User(req.body);
try {
    await User.register(user, req.body.password);
    res.status(302).json({message: MESSAGE.USER_REGISTRATION_SUCCESS}); 
} catch(err) {
      handleErrors(res, err);
}
```

**login**

```
const authRes = await User.authenticate()(req.body.email, req.body.password);
if (authRes && authRes.user) {
    const token = jwt.sign(authRes, config.SECRET);
    if (!authRes.user)
      res.status(400).json(authRes);
    else{
      res.status(302).json({user: authRes.user, token: `JWT ${token}`});                  
    }
} else {
     res.status(401).json({error: MESSAGE.INVALID_LOGIN_ERROR});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using MongoDB**

Perform case-insensitive [regular expression match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#perform-case-insensitive-regular-expression-match) while finding your user document on login function.

```
db.users.find( { email: { $regex: new RegExp(req.body.email, 'i') } } )
```

**Using Javascript**

Convert your email sting to lowercase and then find your user document on login function.

```
db.users.find( { email: req.body.email.toLowerCase() } )
```

*Note : In this method you need to save your email as lowercase in database by using `toLowerCase()` or simply change your schema to `email: { type: String, lowercase: true }`*

Comment: Please check my question. Passport local mongoose is using "User.authenticate()" not find.

Comment: The code given you the way to solve your problem not the code for your application.  Refer [passport-local-mongoose](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose#examples-1) to implement on plugin. Hope its simple to do that.

Comment: Which way you planned/suit for your application from my above answer ?

Answer (score 0):

simply change your schema to email/what name you have given: { type: String, lowercase: true }

It will definitely work in your case. It worked for me.